# MySQL delete large amount of rows and reinsert new data without interruption

Tags: php, mysql

I have a legacy API application that gets a large amount of JSON data via an API call for specific dates.

In order to update the database with the new information, I have to delete all rows related to that date, then loop and insert all new rows. This is about 1200 rows per date. The inserts need to be done as a 'loop' as the JSON data needs extra work done on each row.

This happens regularly - about every 5 minutes.

During this time - there are users regularly accessing the current data 24x7. I've got reports that occasionally when they load the report, there is no data, or the data seems to be incomplete.

My educated guess is they are accessing the report inbetween the delete, and the 'reload' of data. How can I ensure this occurs seemlessly?

What I need to know is will a DB Transaction fix this issue? I know DB Transactions allow for rollback during the operation if something fails - but do they also allow for seamless deletes and updates within the one transaction?

i.e. something like this

```
try {
    $db->beginTransaction();

    $db->query('delete query');
    $db->query('insert query');

    $db->commit();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    $db->rollback();
}
```

Comment: out of curiosity, is your db type innoDB ?

Comment: insert your rows in a temporary database, then when update is complete rename databases

Comment: You should go for transaction, that's correct. I'd parse the json and store in an sql format before starting the transaction, to be able to run a single insert query with all the necessary inputs chained.

Comment: No - its currently MyISAM - but I can (will) convert it to innoDB for this.

Comment: Thanks Felix - I probably should clarify there are other rows for other days on the same table - so it deletes a sub-set of rows. I'll edit my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing is to lock data process in database, for example mysql can lock by row.

[transaction model and locking](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-transaction-model.html)

Also, in mysql, you can write stored procedural to exe all the insert and delete in one time, and during the execution other function cannot access to the data.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you need to use InnoDB. MyISAM doesn't handle any sort of transaction except `LOCK TABLE` which will mess up your users.

Second, make sure that your table is correctly indexed so your `DELETE` query isn't stupid slow--that is, doesn't do a full table scan. Probably that means indexing some DATE or DATETIME field.

Third, don't do your delete like this:

```
DELETE FROM table WHERE DATE(timestampcol) = '2014-01-01'
```

Instead do this:

```
DELETE FROM table WHERE timestampcol  = '2014-01-01'
```

Or, if your `timestampcol` contains both dates and times (that is, it contains non-midnight times), make sure you can use the index by doing it like this:

```
DELETE FROM table WHERE timestampcol >= '2014-01-01'
                    AND timestampcol < '2014-01-01' + INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

Fifth, do use a transaction for this operation. That's basically right in your question.

Sixth, is there any way you can `UPDATE` the rows rather than `DELETE` and `INSERT` them? Can you do this work row by row without disrupting the integrity of the data your users read?  If you can, that might be a way to change the date "under the users' noses" without making them wait while the transaction finishes.

Seventh: This is harder:  You may be able to use a partitioned table, and swap out the partition for the day you're updating.  If you have only 1200 rows per partition this may be giant overkill for what you're doing. But it will scale up at the cost of programming and sysadmin hassle.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think a DB Transaction will fix the issue. In your case, since you delete all the data: uou can speed up the delete statement by doing a "truncate table". A truncate table is faster because it will not keep logs.

Keep in mind: 
Truncate will reset the counter for PK with auto increment